# What specifies the history length of the Clojure REPL?

Tags: clojure, intellij-idea, read-eval-print-loop, leiningen

Where's it set ? I'm using Lein REPL and the LaClojure REPL, I can't find where the history length is set.

Comment: Are you accessing the REPL programmatically? For standard interactive use, a human won't hit the limit. I certainly never have.

Comment: the reason I ask is that my history length is very short and I as a human have hit it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the `idea.cycle.buffer.size` option the idea.properties file (located in the bin directory):

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
This option controls console cyclic buffer: keeps the console output size not higher than the specified buffer size (Kb)
Older lines are deleted. In order to disable cycle buffer use idea.cycle.buffer.size=disabled
--------------------------------------------------------------------
idea.cycle.buffer.size=1024
```

Also in https://stackoverflow.com/a/10793230/151650 Micah mentions the `set history-size 10000` setting in the .inputrc file